# Execute Jar in Python subprocess vs. os.system

Tags: python, jar

I am learning how to exec a jar in python.  I found two ways, 1) subprocess and 2) os.system.  In my code, only os.system works and am I wondering why.

Here is my code.

```
import os

os.chdir('/Users/Jim/Desktop')

import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['java','-cp','dfp-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar', \
           'dfp.axis.v201611.lineitemservices.GetAllLineItems', \
           '-c ads.properties', \
           '-o lineitem-prev.txt', \
           '-l 2017-02-16X00:00:00'], \
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout:
    print line

os.system('java -cp dfp-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar dfp.axis.v201611.lineitemservices.GetAllLineItems -c ads.properties -o lineitem.txt -l 2017-02-20X00:00:00')
```

The subprocess returns these error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at dfp.axis.v201611.lineitemservices.GetAllLineItems.executeIngest(GetAllLineItems.java:46)
at dfp.axis.v201611.GoogleApiHandler.lightTheFuse(GoogleApiHandler.java:103)
at dfp.axis.v201611.lineitemservices.GetAllLineItems.main(GetAllLineItems.java:99)
```

Thank you for your input.
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java program is saying that no date has been passed.
It occurs because you're not passing the arguments in the right way.
Try out this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen(['java','-cp','dfp-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar', \
           'dfp.axis.v201611.lineitemservices.GetAllLineItems', \
           '-c', 'ads.properties', \
           '-o', 'lineitem-prev.txt', \
           '-l', '2017-02-16X00:00:00'], \
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

or this one

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p = Popen('java -cp dfp-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar dfp.axis.v201611.lineitemservices.GetAllLineItems -c ads.properties -o lineitem.txt -l 2017-02-20X00:00:00',
          shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that.  It works perfectly as expected now.  Thanks again!